# Функция поиска по широте и долготе

Tags: python

Помогите, если кто знает решение =) Функция поиска по широте и долготе. Мне нужно, чтобы при вводе неправильного значения она не возбуждала всякие исключения, а писала принтом и снова просила ввод. Широта и долгота должны быть в формате `float()` (т.е. если это строка, он пишет "вводиться должно число"). И еще, мне кажется, что у меня в коде полно лишнего...(

```
def find_airport(lat = None, lon = None):
if lat is None:
    while True:
        lat = float(raw_input('Enter width: '))
        if lat == '-h' or lat == '-help':
            print 'Here need entered weidth, if you can"t this parametre you can skip him'
            continue
        elif lat == '':
            lat = None
            break
        elif float(lat) >= 0:
            print 'The value must be negative!'
            continue
        elif float(lat) < 0: break
    else:
        if lat is None:
            lat = None
        else:
            lat = float(lat)
```

C расчетом `lon` аналогично!

```
if lat and lon:
    search(str(lat), str(lon))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys

def convert(a, b):
    try:
        a, b = float(a), float(b)
    except:
        return (None, None)
    else:
        return (a, b)

def my_input(s):
    inp = raw_input('Enter %s: '%s)
    if inp in ('-h', '-help'):
        print 'Here need entered weidth, if you can"t this parametre you can skip him'
        return None
    return inp

def find_airport(argv):
    if len(argv) == 2:
        lat, lon = argv
    else:
        lat, lon = None, None

    while True:
        lat, lon = convert(lat, lon)
        if lat is None:
            lat = my_input('latitude')
            if lat is not None: lon = my_input('longitude')
        else:
            return lat, lon

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(find_airport(sys.argv[1:]))
```

запуск с параметрами ком. строки: python script.py 12.5 34.6
вывод: (12.5 34.6)
проверку 'The value must be negative!' думаю понятно куда воткнуть

Comment: спасибо, но задача у меня гораздо больше=(

Answer (score 0):

в первом случае вам поможет бесконечный цикл типа

```
while(true) {... break if...}; // это не python так что по аналогии, может какой loop ... end есть
```

и тп.

а во втором случае поможет проверка типов (в python это кажется type() )

```
  if type(variable) == str:
   print "введите число"
   continue
```

Comment: в первом случае, по моему это не питон, а С++))и у меня вроде и есть бесконечный цикл!
а во втором, пробовал, и он как будто не доходит до этого условия...(
и как сделать, чтобы код здесь нормально отображался?)

Comment: четыре пробела от начала строки и будет форматирования строчки как кода. как то так.

Comment: И еще один вопрос)

мне нужно вызывать эту функцию из командной строки с возможной передачей параметров...как это реализовать?
например airport.py -85.6345 40.1364

Comment: хм) опять же не знаю как на питоне но на руби например это переменная ARGV точнее массив, в c это argc, argv[]. ща поищу про питон

Comment: он печатает путь к файлу) ладно))спасибо, пойду разбираться)

Comment: мне кажеться что путь к файлу это первый аргумент, а затем если еще будут аргументы он тоже их выведет

Comment: все равно не понимаю(